# jxBrowser not resetting focus

Tags: eclipse, javafx, swt, chromium, jxbrowser

I am running into a focus issue for the jxBrowser. I integrated the jxBrowser into eclipse as a view and editor, using JavaFX FXCanvas as a container of the jxBrowser. When switching between views within Eclipse, the browser no longer receive focus. It is not possible to use the keyboard, and it is not possible to scroll around the view. Any one know any workaround?

Here is an example of the code:

```
container = new javafx.embed.swt.FXCanvas(parent, SWT.NONE);
container.setLayout(gridLayout);
container.setLayoutData(gridData);

browser = new Browser();        
browserView = new BrowserView(browser);
container.setScene(new javafx.scene.Scene(browserView));
```

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like an issue in SWT-JavaFX integration. To find out whether it's true, please try to reproduce the same behavior using pure JavaFX application without SWT.